# Compress expo apk file size

Tags: react-native, expo

I have used expo to create a simple barcode scanner .When I generated the apk for the same .The apk size is extremely large compared to android studio.

Answer (score 3):

this is explained [in this expo documentation.](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/why-not-expo.html#if-you-need-to-keep-your-app-size-extremely-lean-expo-may-not-be-the-best-choice-the-size-for-an-expo-app-on-ios-is-approximately-25mb-and-android-is-about-20mb-this-is-because-expo-includes-a-bunch-of-apis-regardless-of-whether-or-not-you-are-using-them--this-lets-you-push-over-the-air-updates-to-use-new-apis-but-comes-at-the-cost-of-binary-size-we-will-make-this-customizable-in-the-future-so-you-can-trim-down-the-size-of-your-binaries)

At the moment, expect the smallest APK to be ~25MB.

Comment: Thanks  @Edgar for explanations. I am thinking to start reading the docs before move forward